# Crashlytics not working with Ant

Tags: android, ant, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I am implementing crashlytics with Ant. Imported the jar and required ant scripts. However the package name is not found when building the apk. Back to documentation provided by Fabric

https://crashlytics.com/downloads/ant,

Seems like it's down.

Anyone can confirm if it still working with Ant? Or moving forward with Gradle is the only solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

The URL you're using is out of date and you should use: https://fabric.io/downloads/ant to get the Ant instructions and files.

Comment: Thanks for helping. May I know does the eclipse plugin for crashlytics still working?

Comment: No, we deprecated our Eclipse plugin a bit after Google and Android deprecated their support of Android Developer Tools in Eclipse.

Comment: @Mike Bonnel from Fabric, I have followed all the steps at https://fabric.io/downloads/ant but am getting an error: package io.fabric.sdk.android does not exist

Comment: Can you share more info on when the error happens and any additional details? It's tough to know what's happening with that limited info.